# Update column based on other values from same column without cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a table with one smalldatetime column and one bit column. The former can contain nonconsecutive values, but no duplicates. When ordered chronologically, how can the latter be updated with a value of 1 up to twice every 60 minutes, otherwise 0? The only way I've been able to solve this so far is with a cursor; I'm looking for a solution without a cursor.

An example for clarity. Given the following data:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
     DataTime smalldatetime
    ,Exclude bit
)  

INSERT INTO @Data (DataTime)
     VALUES ('1/1/12')
           ,('1/1/12 0:01')
           ,('1/1/12 0:02')
           ,('1/1/12 0:03')
           ,('1/1/12 0:59')
           ,('1/1/12 1:00')
           ,('1/1/12 1:01')
           ,('1/1/12 1:02')
           ,('1/1/12 1:03')
           ,('1/1/12 1:30')
           ,('1/1/12 3:39')
           ,('1/1/12 4:37')
           ,('1/1/12 4:38')
           ,('1/1/12 4:39')
           ,('1/1/12 4:40')
```

Update to this:

```
DataTime               Exclude
2012-01-01 00:00:00    1
2012-01-01 00:01:00    1
2012-01-01 00:02:00    0
2012-01-01 00:03:00    0
2012-01-01 00:59:00    0
2012-01-01 01:00:00    1
2012-01-01 01:01:00    1
2012-01-01 01:02:00    0
2012-01-01 01:03:00    0
2012-01-01 01:30:00    0
2012-01-01 03:39:00    1
2012-01-01 04:37:00    1
2012-01-01 04:38:00    0
2012-01-01 04:39:00    1
2012-01-01 04:40:00    0
```

Cursor solution:

```
DECLARE ExcludeRows CURSOR
    FOR SELECT DataTime
          FROM @Data
         ORDER BY DataTime

DECLARE @DataTime smalldatetime, @ExcludedCount int

OPEN ExcludeRows
    FETCH NEXT FROM ExcludeRows INTO @DataTime
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ExcludedCount = ISNULL(SUM(CONVERT(int, Exclude)), 0)
          FROM @Data
         WHERE DataTime BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -60 + 1, @DataTime) AND DATEADD(MINUTE,-1, @DataTime)

        UPDATE @Data
             SET Exclude = CASE WHEN @ExcludedCount < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           WHERE DataTime = @DataTime

        FETCH NEXT FROM ExcludeRows INTO @DataTime
    END
CLOSE ExcludeRows
DEALLOCATE ExcludeRows

SELECT *
  FROM @Data
 ORDER BY DataTime
```

Comment: can you share your solution using the cursor (for full understanding of how you generate your output)?

Comment: Looking at the values in the 4th hour range, why do the minutes 37 and 39 get set? Why not 37 and 38?

Comment: 4:38 is not set because 2 minutes in the previous 59 are set (3:39 and 4:37).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the answer to my comment is "typo", then try an updateable CTE. Use row_number and partition by the date and hour. Then you simply update those rows where row_number returns 1 or 2.

```
with cte as (
  select Datatime, Exclude, 
         row_number() over (partition by cast(Datatime as date), datepart(hour, Datatime) order by Datatime) as rno
    from @Data 
)
update cte set Exclude = case when rno <= 2 then 1 else 0 end
;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a7ed1156351de7236c3f91f8b10e5319) to demonstrate. Note - NEVER use two digits years.

Comment: Close but not correct.  4:38 should not be set.

Comment: So it is a sliding window based on the time of each value - not a fixed 1 hour window. Which needs a more recursive approach

Comment: Yes, precisely.